# При отправке формы, закрывается окно facebox

Tags: jquery, wordpress

В модальном окне `facebox` выводится форма с чекбоксами.

1. При нажатии кнопки **отправить**, надо проверить выбран ли чекбокс и если выбран один из последних двух, заполнено ли появившееся поле.
2. Проблема в том, что когда идет `submit`, окно facebox закрывается. Если в facebox невозможно отправить форму, без закрытия окна, то нужно как-то извлечь данные из формы, подставив их в `$.get();` чтобы менять контент в окне  без его перезагрузки.

Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
<form id="pichform" method="post" action="">
<div id="search-modal-title">Укажите в чём нарушение</div>

<input value="Фотографии не отображаются" name="prichina" type="radio" id="1" /> <label style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" for="1">Фотографии не отображаются</label><br />
<input value="На фото не грибы и ничего похожего на грибы" name="prichina" type="radio" id="2" /> <label style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" for="2">На фото не грибы и ничего похожего на грибы</label><br />
<input value="Фото слишком плохого качества" name="prichina" type="radio" id="3" /> <label style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" for="3">Фото слишком плохого качества</label><br />
<input value="Мытые либо слишком старые грибы" name="prichina" type="radio" id="4" /> <label style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" for="4">Мытые либо слишком старые грибы</label><br />
<input value="Грибы разных видов в одном вопросе" name="prichina" type="radio" id="5" /> <label style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" for="5">Грибы разных видов в одном вопросе</label><br />
<input value="Дубликат" name="prichina" type="radio" id="6" /> <label style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" for="6">Дубликат</label><br />
<span id="urls" style="display: none;">
    Адреса дубликатов:<br />
    <textarea name="urls" style="width: 300px; height: 50px;"></textarea><br />
</span>
<input value="Другое" name="prichina" type="radio" id="7" /> <label style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" for="7">Другое</label><br />
<span id="drugoe" style="display: none;">
    Укажите причину:<br />
    <textarea name="drugoe" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;"></textarea><br />
</span>

</form>
<button style="margin-top: 20px;" onclick="SubmForm(); false;">отправить</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#1,#2,#3,#4,#5').change(function(){
        $('#urls').hide();
        $('#drugoe').hide();
    }); 
    $('#6').change(function(){
        $('#urls').show();
        $('#drugoe').hide();
    });
    $('#7').change(function(){
        $('#urls').hide();
        $('#drugoe').show();
    });
});

function SubmForm() {
    //проверки
    if ($('#1,#2,#3,#4,#5').change()){
        $( "#pichform" ).submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Во-первых `onclick="SubmForm(); return false;"`. Во-вторых - в чем смысл этой проверки `if ($('#1,#2,#3,#4,#5').change())`? В-третьих, вызов `$("#pichform").submit();` приводит к перезагрузке страницы, поэтому Вам кажется, что "окно facebox закрывается".

Comment: `($('#1,#2,#3,#4,#5').change())` - это я хотел проверить форму на наличие выбранного чекбокса